# How to perform date operations in bash

Tags: bash, shell, date, datetime, timezone-offset

Basically, I want to take a time, and day of the week, in UTC+8, and adjust the datetime object to a given UTC offset, within bash, I don't have any code to show because I'm not sure how to start attempting this in the first place honestly

(I'm writing a custom script for a friend who lives in UTC+8 and want to make the input as easy as possible for them, basically they just give it a time in their timezone, and a day of the week, and it'll tell them what date and time that'll be in a different timezone, for an overarching purpose)

Comment: Look up GNU date

Comment: bash doesn't have datetime objects, or any other sort of objects -- it has strings. It sort-of has integers, but those are really just strings of digits. You need to keep track of what format the strings in your variables are, and be sure the tools you pass them to understand that format correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For a reference, look at the section 1 of the manual page for "date":

In your shell, just type: `man 1 date`

or see the online man page:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

One way is to parse the date into the number of seconds since epoch (since 1970), and then convert that number of seconds into the format you want:

For example:

```
$ date +%s  --date='2022-12-27 11:30:17 +008'
1672140137

$ date +%c --date='@1672140137'
Tue 27 Dec 2022 06:22:17 AM EST
```

or you could also convert to ISO format then back to local time

```
$ date -Iseconds --date='TZ="GMT" 2022-12-22 11:33:44 +08'
2022-12-21T22:33:44-05:00
$ date --date='2022-12-21T22:33:44-05:00'
Wed 21 Dec 2022 10:33:44 PM EST
```

I hope this helps you get started with some ideas for converting to/from different timezones.

Also, to help with user input, you can show the current month calendar using `cal`

```
$ cal
   December 2022      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29 30 31  
                      
$ date --date='Fri 08:30'
Fri 30 Dec 2022 08:30:00 AM EST
```

In the above example, I specified "Fri 08:30" which gets set to the next Friday at 08:30 in the morning for my local timezone.